# The Constructor is getting undefined in the Selenium Web driver project

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In the Selenium Web Driver project, the Constructor DragAndDrop(WebDriver) is getting undefined in the dragAndDropTest(), can anyone suggest how can I fix this problem? I have added the error screenshot and span element details

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class DragAndDrop {  
    WebDriver driver;

    public DragAndDrop(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void draganItem(){
           //Element on which need to drag.
        WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='todrag']/span"));
            //Element on which need to drop.        
        WebElement target =driver.findElement(By.id("mydropzone"));                 
            //Using Actions class for drag and drop.        
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);                  
           //Using Action for Dragged and dropped.
        Action dragAndDrop = act.moveToElement(source)
                                .clickAndHold(source)
                                .moveToElement(target)
                                .release(target)
                                .build();
                                dragAndDrop.perform();      
                            }

    public String droppedItem(){
        return driver.findElement(By.id("droppedlist")).getText();      
    }



}
```

// Below is the DragAndDropTest Test //

```
public class DragAndDropTest {  

        @Test
        public void dragAndDropTest(){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Project\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");   
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            DragAndDrop dragandDrop = new DragAndDrop(driver);



        }

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is `DragAndDrop` in the same package as `DragAndDropTest`?

Comment: No 'DragAndDrop' under different package called 'pages' and 'DragAndDropTest' under tests

Comment: Than you need to add import to `DragAndDrop`.

Comment: Really helpful, I was importing the wrong one. Solved the problem,